# Missing file in amd64 package, black screen after grub

Tags: 14.04, amd-graphics

I started to get black screeb after grub so i searched for it a lot. And last days i played with amd driver, so problem probably related with it, then searched for missing files with `debsums -s`
and found one
`debsums: missing file /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/old.libgbm.so.1.0.0 (from libgbm1-lts-vivid:amd64 package`

then i tried to reinstall this package

`apt-get install --reinstall libgbm1-lts-vivid:amd64 
Reinstallation of libgbm1-lts-vivid:amd64 is not possible, it cannot be downloaded`

so i am stucked here.

and i also tried 
`aptitude reinstall libgbm1-lts-vivid:amd64`
but got 3 errors, I don't remember but if it is needed i can check it.